# How to align 2 elements on the same line with the second one on priority?

Tags: css, alignment

I would like to align two text elements on the same line. The second element must have the priority on the first one. I mean the **first** element (the title) **can be cut** if too long, but the **second** one (the price) **must stay full**.

This is what I've done so far. It's working on Chrome, not on Firefox.

```css
h3{
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 340px;
}

.price {
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #1abc9c;
  background: yellow;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
                <h3>
                  <span class="price">6 500 €</span>

                  <a class="title">Here is my long title, which is a very long one!</a>
                </h3>
```

This image shows what I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the demo link
http://jsfiddle.net/9g40gh0q/1/

What i have done is, set the container (h3) to a set width (340px)
Then i assumed you wanted to reserve 25% of the width for the price, i.e 85px and the title to 75% of h3.

Works fine in IE, FF and Chrome.

HTML

```
<h3>
    <a class="title">Here is my long title, which is a very long one!</a>
    <span class="price">6 500 €</span>
</h3>
```

CSS

```
    h3 {
    width: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    clear: both;
}
h3 .title{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
h3 .price {
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the second width may change (for example it can be 12 €, 13 500 € or even 1 240 000 €) so your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML includes `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>`

this could cause firefox to not read your work

Comment: What do you mean by "your HTML includes"? ... includes what?

Comment: @Dacobah fixed it, sorry

Answer (score -1):

```css
  h3{
      font-size: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 340px;
  
    }

.price {
  
     //padding-left: 15px;
     color: #1abc9c;
     background: yellow;
     float: right;

    }
```

```html
                <h3>
                  <span class="price">6 500 €</span>

                  <a class="title">Here is my long title, which is a very long one!</a>
</h3>
```